# Python mongoengine How to query an EmbeddedDocument

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I am trying to query document in mongodb.

Schema is below:

```
class Book(EmbeddedDocument):
    name = StringField()
    description = StringField()

class Category(EmbeddedDocument):
    name = StringField()
    books = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Book))

class Main(Document):
    category = EmbeddedDocumentField(Category)
```

What i need is to retrieve Book with name say "Python For Dummies".
I tried using

```
Main.objects(category__book__name="Python For Dummies")[0]
```

as well as

```
Main.objects(__raw__={'category.book.name': 'Python For Dummies'})[0]
```

Both are retrieving a single Main document out of the list which in which there is a book with name "Python For Dummies". But what i want is the Book embedded document alone not the entire document. My need is to list that single book information. In my case, now i have to traverse again through the books list of the Main document and match the name with the book's name to retrieve the correct book - I think there must be better ways in mongoengine/python to achieve this.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit the output with `only()`.

**Query**

```
Main.objects(category__books__name="Python For Dummies").only("category.books")
```

**Result**

```
[{"category": {"books": [{"name": "Python For Dummies"", "description": "a test book"}]}}]
```

But that would not get you exactly what you want. To achive this, you would need to use `aggregate` and `$unwind`.

**Query**

```
list(Main.objects.aggregate(
    {"$match":{"category.books.name":"Python For Dummies"} },
    {"$unwind": "$category.books" },
    {"$group":{"_id": None, "books":{"$push":"$category.books"}}}
 ))
```

**Result**

```
{'_id': None,'books': [{'description': 'a test book', 'name': 'Python For Dummies"'}]}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. But i am still getting the same entire response while using the first "only()" option. And second one was throwing an error as unrecognized field "cursor. - Ranjith

Comment: Even if the only works, it is fine since i could extract.